# Powershell "InternetExplorer.Application" click on dropdown

Tags: html, powershell, internet-explorer, dom, automation

I am trying to click on "CSV (comma delimited)" using Powershell so I can be able to save this report.

[image: Dropdown List]]

Here is the code behind the dropdown.

```
<div class="MenuBarBkGnd" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_Menu" style="display: block; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
                                        <div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="XML file with report data" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('XML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="XML file with report data">XML file with report data</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="CSV (comma delimited)" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('CSV');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="CSV (comma delimited)">CSV (comma delimited)</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="PDF" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('PDF');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="PDF">PDF</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="MHTML (web archive)" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('MHTML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="MHTML (web archive)">MHTML (web archive)</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="Excel" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Excel">Excel</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="TIFF file" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('IMAGE');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="TIFF file">TIFF file</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="Word" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('WORDOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Word">Word</a>
                                        </div><div class="HoverButton">
                                            <a title="TXT (Pipe delimited)" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('PIPE');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="TXT (Pipe delimited)">TXT (Pipe delimited)</a>
                                        </div>
                                    <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 26px; height: 368px; position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0.05; background-color: black;"></div></div>
```

The code below brings up the dropdown list.

```
$DownloadButton = $ie.Document.getElementById('ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImgDown')
$DownloadButton.click()
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I posted the html code for the dropdown. I'm not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: What you have tried with powershell cmd?

Comment: I have tried with Powershell but I don't know exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Also, I have got it working with SendKeys but there will be many things running on this machine that cause it to lose focus so I didn't think SendKeys would be the best option.

Comment: Post code you tried with powershell

Comment: Code has been posted.

Comment: Is that SSRS report? I'd also suggest to use Selenium with firefox or chrome instead. Firefox even has a macro recording, so it will follow your "clicks"

Comment: I suggest you do not post the code as an image. You can use the code snippet to post the code. So that we can use that code to test the issue. I try to search and found that other examples also show a similar click method that you had already tested. Let us know whether you are available to use VBA or Selenium code. We can try to provide a sample code for it.

Comment: Updated the code of the menu.  Also, we will be using Active Batch to automate but I could use anything really to make it work. I can do some research on using firefox/selenium. Please someone point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make a test with your code. I put one alert message on the click of CSV (comma delimited) option. So when code clicks on that specific option it will show an alert message. Which indicates that code clicks the correct element.

Here is modified HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function abc()
{
    alert("Clicked...");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="MenuBarBkGnd" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl09_ctl04_ctl00_Menu" style="display: block; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
                                        <div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="XML file with report data" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('XML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="XML file with report data">XML file with report data</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="CSV (comma delimited)" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="abc()" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="CSV (comma delimited)">CSV (comma delimited)</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="PDF" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('PDF');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="PDF">PDF</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="MHTML (web archive)" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('MHTML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="MHTML (web archive)">MHTML (web archive)</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="Excel" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Excel">Excel</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="TIFF file" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('IMAGE');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="TIFF file">TIFF file</a>
                                        </div><div class="DisabledButton">
                                            <a title="Word" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('WORDOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Word">Word</a>
                                        </div><div class="HoverButton">
                                            <a title="TXT (Pipe delimited)" class="ActiveLink" style="padding: 8px 8px 3px; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewerControl').exportReport('PIPE');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="TXT (Pipe delimited)">TXT (Pipe delimited)</a>
                                        </div>
                                    <div style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 26px; height: 368px; position: absolute; z-index: -1; opacity: 0.05; background-color: black;"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

VBA code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


    IE.Visible = True


    URL = "D:\Backup20190913\tests\391.html"


    IE.Navigate URL


    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    i = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a").Item(1).innerHTML


    If i = "CSV (comma delimited)" Then
        IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a").Item(1).Click

    End If

    Set IE = Nothing


End Sub
```

This VBA code will find the link and try to match its innerHTML with the static value. If it gets match then it will click it.

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your own requirements. If you have any questions then you can let us know about that.

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful. I feel like I'm so close. This is what I am trying right now: ```$DownloadCSV = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | ?{$_.innerHTML -eq "CSV (comma delimited)"}
$DownloadCSV.innerText
$DownloadCSV.click()``` but it is not working...returns ```CSV (comma delimited)
System.__ComObject```

Comment: Actually, it worked! The website had logged me out due to inactivity from last night! You are awesome! Well, all of you are awesome! Thanks so much!